# encoding question in perl

Tags: perl, encoding, mojibake

I have an encoding question and would like to ask for help. I notice if I choose "UTF-8" as encoding, there are (at least) two double quotes `"` and `“`. But when I choose "ISO-8859-1" as the encoding, I see the latter double quote becomes `¡°`, or sometimes for example `â€œ`.

Could anyone please explain why this is the case? How can match `“` and replace it with `"` using regexp in perl?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Define “to choose UTF-8 as encoding”.  Do you mean `use utf8` for source code, or `use open qw(:std :utf8)` for streams, or something else altogether?

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484/why-does-modern-perl-avoid-utf-8-by-default/6163129#6163129).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ISO-8859-1 is a one-byte-per-character encoding.  The fancy Unicode double-quotes are not in the ISO-8859-1 character set.  So what you are seeing is a multi-byte character represented as a sequence of ISO-8859-1 bytes.

To match these weird things, see the [perlunicode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html) man page, especially the \x{...} and \N{...} escape sequences.

To answer your question, try \x{201C} to match the Unicode LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK and \x{201D} to match the RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK.  You missed the latter in your question :-).

[update]

I should have provided my reference...  Some nice gentleman in the UK has a page on [ASCII and Unicode quotation marks](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html).  The plain vanilla ASCII/ISO-8859-1 double-quote is just called QUOTATION MARK.

Comment: thank you for your answer. :) So what is the name of the other plain double quotation mark?

Comment: @Qiang:  Yes.  I added an update with the link I should have included in the first place

Comment: Best to `use charnames ":full"` and thence the likes of `\N{EFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK}` and the like. I mislike magic numbers in code, and 0x201C is certainly one such.

Comment: @Qiang: You should get [the uninames script](http://training.perl.com/scripts/uninames) if you want to know the names of code points. There is a lot more unicode-related stuff there [in that directory](http://training.perl.com/scripts/), too.

Answer (score -1):

May be this [`Old post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963510/unable-to-encode-to-iso-8859-1-encoding-for-some-chars-using-perl-encode-module) will help..